# Signing in with Facebook - FBSession questions

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I've been trying to integrate Facebook and came across some issues and questions.

### 1.

I have implemented the following method in viewDidLoad:

```
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:NO completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                [self sessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error];
            }];
```

When there's a token cached, the block is executed as expected.
But, when there isn't a token cached, the block isn't executed at all.
**Is this a normal behaviour? If so, when is the block executed?**

### 2.

I've been said that access tokens are expired at some point.
**Should I be worried about what to do when a token is expired, or Facebook handles it automatically?**

### 3.

What FBSession actually means?
As I understand - the FBSession manages the token and the user authentication,
Yet, I don't understand what does it mean to "open a session" or what the **FBSessionStates** represent.

**When is the FBSession created? Right when the app loads?**

### 4.

I've found that graph that should explain the FBSessionsStates:
[image: A graph represents the FBSessionStates. Taken from Understanding Sessions tutorial on Facebook.]

After reading the graph, I still don't understand the flow - **when are FBSessionStateCreated & FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded the current state of the session?**

---

As you can see, I have many questions about the whole process.
I've tried to organize the questions in a way that other people seeing this in the future, won't be having the struggles I'm having.

Thank you.